# Javascript elliptical point multiplication algorithm

Tags: javascript, elliptic-curve

The following is an implementation of elliptical curve [Point Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication), but it's not working as expected (using recent Chrome / Node with BigInt for illustration):

```
const bi0 = BigInt(0)
const bi1 = BigInt(1)
const bi2 = BigInt(2)
const bi3 = BigInt(3)

const absMod = (n, p) => n < bi0 ? (n % p) + p : n % p

export function pointAdd (xp, yp, xq, yq, p) {
  const lambda = (yq - yp) / (xq - xp)
  const x = absMod(lambda ** bi2 - xp - xq, p)
  const y = absMod(lambda * (xp - x) - yp, p)
  return { x, y }
}

export function pointDouble (xp, yp, a, p) {
  const numer = bi3 * xp ** bi2 + a
  const denom = (bi2 * yp) ** (p - bi2)
  const lambda = (numer * denom) % p
  const x = absMod(lambda ** bi2 - bi2 * xp, p)
  const y = absMod(lambda * (xp - x) - yp, p)
  return { x, y }
}

export function pointMultiply (d, xp, yp, a, p) {
  const add = (xp, yp, { x, y }) => pointAdd(xp, yp, x, y, p)
  const double = (x, y) => pointDouble(x, y, a, p)
  const recur = ({ x, y }, n) => {
    if (n === bi0) { return { x: bi0, y: bi0 } }
    if (n === bi1) { return { x, y } }
    if (n % bi2 === bi1) { return add(x, y, recur({ x, y }, n - bi1)) }
    return recur(double(x, y), n / bi2)
  }
  return recur({ x: xp, y: yp }, d)
}
```

Given a [known curve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64456) with properties, the above succeeds for points P2 - P5, but starts failing at P6 onwards:

```
const p = BigInt('17')
const a = BigInt('2')
const p1 = { x: BigInt(5), y: BigInt(1) }

const d = BigInt(6)
const p6 = pointMultiply(d, p1.x, p1.y, a, p)
p6.x === BigInt(16) // incorrect value of 8 was returned
p6.y === BigInt(13) // incorrect value of 14 was returned
```

The known curve has values:

```
P   X    Y
—————————— 
1   5    1
2   6    3
3  10    6
4   3    1
5   9   16
6  16   13
7   0    6
8  13    7
9   7    6
10  7   11
```

I'm not sure if I misunderstand the algorithm or I've made an error in the implementation.

Comment: I don't know javascript well, so are the basic arithmetic operators `+, -,/` and `**` overloaded to work with `BigInt` operands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know javascript very well, so the code confuses me. But ...

In function `pointAdd`, and everywhere else, "division" must be done mod p. You're evidently doing it correctly in `pointDouble`, but not in `pointAdd`. In `pointAdd`, use the same pattern: Instead of

```
const lambda = (yq - yp) / (xq - xp)
```

do

```
const numer = yq - yp
const denom = (xq - xp) ** (p - bi2)
const lambda = (numer * denom) % p
```

though I would think it would much clearer and less error prone to simply have a modular inverse function instead of computing X<sup>p-2</sup> everywhere you need it.